# FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) nothing is being returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i use this function to call my database

```
function get_prescriptionWith_4($ID){
    $sql = "SELECT prescriptions FROM tblprescriptions WHERE `ID`='$ID'";
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    return @$row;
}
```

my database table looks like this..

```
ID   |       prescription
1    |    Med  (gen) 20 -- #20/1X per day --morning--for  30 days/,
1    |    test (test) 23 -- #343/1X per day --morning and noon-- 120 days23/,   
          samp (rere) 44 -- #34/1X per day --morning-- 7 days44/, 
1    |    asd (asd) 22 -- #222/3X per day --morning noon and evening--30 days/,   
          qw (wq) 44 -- #222/3X per day --morning noon and evening--60 days/, 
          1233 (123) 21 -- #123213/1X per day --morning---  60 days/,
```

what i wanted to achieve is to load all prescription with the same id and since row prescription have multiple data inside it i use `explode` to separate the data with , when i tried to use `Fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` i only returns the first prescription i think that using fetchAll might be better to fetch all data from my database..

```
$pres_array3=$patient->get_prescriptionWith_4($ID);
$new_array3=explode(',',$pres_array3,-1);
```

but when i use `echo $new_array3` to check nothing is being return if it is on `fetchAll`

Comment: Errrm sorry, that is not a properly prepared statement at all to begin with. Debugging is easy though, instead of returning the data back you can run some error checking functions to see if any pdo errors are being returned

Comment: @HankyPanky the prepared statement is valid, OP is only vulnerable to SQL injections. Please use parameterized statements instead.

Comment: that is actually fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to begin with but my problem is if i use fetchAll nothing is being returned that is the reason why i posted that since i think that is my problem..

Comment: `print_r($this->dbh->errorInfo());`

Answer (score 3):

1) Your prepared statement is wrong/misused

```
$sql = "SELECT prescriptions FROM tblprescriptions WHERE `ID` = :id";
$query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':id' => $ID]);
```

2) `$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns array, so `$row['prescriptions']` does not exist and it would throw warning of undefined index `prescriptions`. A correct version would be

```
if($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT prescriptions FROM tblprescriptions WHERE `ID` = :id";
$query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':id' => $ID]);
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
   return @$row;`

is this correct to return all row data ??

Comment: Please don't mind the edit. +1

Comment: what i actually wanted to is to fetch all the data with the same id.. that is the reason why i use fetchAll and as you said that the approach i made is incorrect..

Comment: i updated my function to give you better understanding on what i want to achieve..

Comment: @LionSmith Why even your `id` is non-unique? ID must be auto-incremented or at least unique for faster database work and enabling indexing

Comment: @Justinas it is unique tho. i just make it simple..

Comment: i ithink fetchAll is not the best approach to my question thanks by the way for giving me additional information :D really appreciated

Comment: @LionSmith So if ID is unique, than you will always get max 1 match from database, why `fetchAll` then?

Comment: check the answer.....i only tried fetchAll to think that this is the best way to achieve what i want..

Answer (score 0):

so since `fetchAll(PDO:ASSOC)` gives me nothing...i use this approach instead..

```
$prescriptions = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $prescriptions[] = $row;
    }
return $prescriptions;
```

and then
`$pres_array3=$patient->get_prescriptionWith_4($patientID);`

```
<?php 
    foreach ($pres_array3 as $key => $value) {
       $prescription =  $value['prescriptions'];
       $new_array3=explode(',',$prescription,-1);
        foreach($new_array3 as $value) {    

?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value?>"  />

<?php } } ?>
```

the reason why i use multiple loop is because on the 1st loop i get all the array data and then explode it to separate the data then loop again since the explode return `array` not the element..

Comment: Just for reference this understanding is incorrect *fetchAll(PDO:ASSOC) gives me nothing*. If `fetch()` is giving you something on a dataset then 100% gauranteed `fetchAll()` will also give *something*

Comment: One reason you didn't get any result from it is that this statement has a syntax error `$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`